# upgraded to google universal analytics change

Tags: google-analytics

If I upgrade to google universal analytics and add

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Do I also need to change all my event tracking and other features? for example

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do. If you switch to using [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) (the universal analytics library), then the old `_gaq` variable will not be defined on your page and the above code will error. Analytics.js uses the `ga` variable and the syntax is slightly different.

The example you listed would look like this in analytics.js:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind');
```

Here is a link to a developer guide on implementing event tracking using analytics.js:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events